# Breach on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, tar, ubuntu-14.04

I am using `ubuntu 14.04` and I want to `install` new browser http://`breach`.cc/
I've downloaded zipped file. but I do not know what I do after this?
Can anyone help me?

Comment: (As an aside: please don't abuse `\`code\`` for random formatting.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
~/src$ git clone git@github.com:breach/mod_strip.git
~/src$ cd mod_strip
~/src$ npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

The first thing you need to do is extracting it in a folder, let's make it your desktop. You can extract an archive right clicking on it and choosing the appropriate entry. It should create a new folder with a similar name, e.g. program-1.2.3. Now you need to open your terminal and then go to that directory:

```
cd /home/yourusername/Desktop/breach-v0.3.20-alpha.5-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Make sure you first read a file called INSTALL or INSTALL.txt or README. Check if there is any of these files with the ls command, and then display the right one with:

```
xdg-open INSTALL
```

The file will contain the right indications to go on with the compiling process. Usually the three "classical" steps are:

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: Don't work!!!!!

Comment: Well, *what* didn't work, @Sio?

Answer (score -1):

After searching and tweaking i have figured out a solution to successfully run the Breach browser in Ubuntu 14.04. I have compiled a tutorial for it. Please have a look.

http://codeforgeek.com/2014/08/download-install-breach-browser-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: Please post answers that provide information without the need to go to your personal blog. Now, this is just spamming your blog, more so as you also posted this on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: How it could be spam ? if there is a resource at external link.

Comment: If you're trying to fool us into thinking that website is not your own, then as a start you shouldn't have included your picture both here and on your blog. This is promotion for your site, I feel.

Comment: Why to make people fool if they are already. I am hobby blogger and i blog about the programming issues. If i post link which have no such information then you can say it is spam. I am not promoting,i am just helping via my blog. Hope it's clear to you.

Comment: I see that your link-only answer on Ask Ubuntu was already deleted? Please see [Avoid overt self-promotion](http://superuser.com/help/behavior) and [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers)

Comment: I had no such clue to promote my links...it is just i don't wanted to re post things which i already wrote.

Comment: Meanwhile you could already have copied the main commands here... ;-)

Comment: If it's about to copy a command , i will. But i am no cheap Spammer. I am passionate blogger trying to help people. That's it.